# Phonegap and email or zip to server

Tags: android, cordova, iso

I could use some help. I’m trying to create a phonegap app for iOS and Android. In this app you should be able to

- type your user credentials (name, company, email and telephone number) and save it. This part in working for me.
- Create a case where you type some text and take a number of pictures – hereafter you should press send and the text with the pictures will be sent to a predefined email address. – This part isn’t working for me

Is it possible to do that with Phonegap? And if yes then how do I do that?  If no, will it then be possible to zip the text and the pictures and then sent it to a server of some kind (ftp, dropbox ect?)

Best regards

Jacob

Comment: can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. You can send image's data (binary data) and text to server. At server end you can create images by using the image data and send the email as per your requirement.

You can also compress images by reducing image quality with the help of phonegap api as well and it will be helpful to minimize your request in size.

If you are using Ajax to send request to server then you should use cross domain option true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to use the server method you provided. If I am able to :)